# Few PHP script E-Mails Not getting delivered

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have created folders under my domain.
Emails scripts in folder-1 are getting delivered but scripts in folder-2 show message = "email sent successfully". But these emails are not receiving in email address.

I am using phpmailer

---

When this sampleemail.php file is kept in **Folder1**, Email **get delivered**. But when **same file** is kept in **Folder2, Error Message is there**.

Code is as follows :

```
<?
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


$from_add = "name@my-web-site.com"; 

$to_add = "myemail@gmail.com"; //<-- put your yahoo/gmail email address here

$subject = "Test Subject";
$message = "Test Message";

$headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
{
    $msg = "Mail sent OK";
} 
else 
{
   $msg = "Error sending email!";
}
}
?>
```

And HTML Sample Form As Follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Test form to email</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $msg ?>
<p>
<form action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check spam for emails

Comment: @VipinSoni I didn't get your point. Emails are not in spam folders also..

Comment: Can you explain more this: "But when same file is kept in Folder2, Error Message is there.". Which error message?

Comment: You're not using PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see you are NOT using "PHPMailer", but "PHP's mailer".

Regarding your problem of undelivered emails and error message, here are some general hints:

1. If you send HTML mail, always send a multipart email containing both, HTML and TEXT
2. Don't use "X-Mailer: PHP". There are mail servers who will give your mail an increased spam score just because of that.
3. If you get an error, try this:

   ```
   $errLevel = error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   mail(...);
   error_reporting($errLevel);
   ```
4. Try using a different delivery method (smpt, sendmail, ...)

Comment: Why would you disable E_NOTICE? That's a terrible suggestion. You want notices since they usually indicate bad/terrible/buggy  code!

Comment: @ThiefMaster Having E_NOTICE or not doesn't matter at this place since `mail()`-errors are not notices.

Comment: @ThiefMaster If you would keep, even tho it doesn't matter for the one function call, thats ok. But please don't get personal because you'd do it differently. There is no right or wrong in this case.

Comment: Not sure where it sounded personal. Usually code that triggers notices *is* quite bad.

Comment: It sounded personal at "terrible suggestion", since it implies I'm giving "terrible suggestions". :D And yes, you are right, if code triggers notices it IS bad. As I said, it is just for that one function call and disabling notices at this position makes sure he will only receive an output related to possible errors during the `mail()`-process.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use PHPmailer because it has the function which you needed. The reason i am not suggest you use your method because it need to change the sendmail() function in your localhost.

For example: if u using xampp, you must go into the sendmail directory and go for sendmail.php to edit the SMTP to mail.google.com and so on.

Please try this tutorial:
http://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/phpmailer-ultimate-tutorial/

Hope it can helps you.

Comment: That's based on obsolete code - just use the better examples that are included with PHPMailer.